# correct syntax for route name when routing with annotations in presence or url parameters

Tags: php, symfony, routes, annotations

I am using annotations in a controller to resolve url "/registerded"

```
/**
 * @Route("/registered", name="registered_user")
 */
public function registeredAction(){
    return $this->render('MyBundle:Default:registered.html.twig');
}
```

This works ok, without arguments . It works good when I refer to it as "path" defined with "name" parameter in annotation. Exactly I use it in another action of the same controller:

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('/registered_user');
```

This is all ok.

Now I 'd like to have a working url like "/registerded/45" and I need to refer to it with a path name such above. I think something like :

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('/registered_user/45');
```

I would like to use annotations (I know how to make it under routing_dev.yml and so on, but I want to do it with annotations in the controller).
I've tried

```
/**
 * @Route("/registered/{id}", name="registered_user/{id}")
 */
public function registeredAction($id){
    return $this->render('MyBundle:Default:registered.html.twig');
}
```

But it's not the correct configuration for name parameter. I receive :

```
Unable to generate a URL for the named route "/registered_user/45" as such route does not exist.
```

Please is there someone can suggest me the right syntax for name parameter in annotation when I need to pass a url parameter as with the redirect url above ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to add `/` prefix, when generating a url address.

Also, if you have troubles using a method from Symfony, you can always look how is defined and what arguments expects.

To answer your question, since you already added name to your route `registered_user`, in order to get URL like `/registered/45`, you need to edit your route path only, and pass the required arguments.

So, for this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/registered/{id}", name="registered_user")
 */
```

your redirect call should look like this:

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('registered_user', array(
    'id' => 45
));
```

A copy from `Controller.php`

```
/**
 * Returns a RedirectResponse to the given route with the given parameters.
 *
 * @param string $route      The name of the route
 * @param array  $parameters An array of parameters
 * @param int    $status     The status code to use for the Response
 *
 * @return RedirectResponse
 */
protected function redirectToRoute($route, array $parameters = array(), $status = 302)
{
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl($route, $parameters), $status);
}
```

Comment: You're right I should give a look at function definition… Thanks for the correct answer.